# Genexus StackOverflow

Tags: app, twitter

[image: Genexus Stack Twitter Account]

### About

Inspired by [C# StackOverflow](https://twitter.com/CSharpStack) I decided to create a bot that would scan for the newly [Genexus](http://www.genexus.com) tagged questions and twit them out loud.

### Contact

Questions, comments? reach out [@sebagomez](https://twitter.com/sebagomez)

### Code

I used [Genexus](http://www.genexus.com) to develop it.

Check the twitter bot out at [GenexusStack](https://twitter.com/genexusstack)

"Documentation" at the [Genexus Wiki](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30686,Genexus+Stack,)